# AKS Horizontal Pod Autoscaling - missing request for cpu

Tags: azure-aks

I have been trying to set up an Kubernetes 1.13 AKS deployment to use HPA, and I keep running into a problem:

```
NAME                     REFERENCE                           TARGETS         MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
dev-hpa-poc   Deployment/dev-hpa-poc   <unknown>/50%   1         4         2          65m
```

Describing the HPA gives me these events:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                        Age                   From                       Message
  ----     ------                        ----                  ----                       -------
  Warning  FailedComputeMetricsReplicas  5m4s (x200 over 55m)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  failed to get cpu utilization: missing request for cpu
  Warning  FailedGetResourceMetric       3s (x220 over 55m)    horizontal-pod-autoscaler  missing request for cpu
```

It doesn't appear to be able to actually retrieve CPU usage. I have specified cpu and memory usage in the deployment YAML:

```
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 128Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 800m
            memory: 1024Mi
```

The system:metrics-server is running and healthy, too, so that's not it. I can monitor pod health and CPU usage from the Azure portal. Any ideas as to what I'm missing? Could this potentially be a permissions issue?

Answer (score 5):

for `missing request for [x]` make sure that **all** the containers in the pod have requests declared.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the reason was that other deployment haven't resource limits. You should add resources **for each pod and deployment** in namespace.

Comment: I had resource limits on the application container, but I was also injecting a sidecar proxy service that did not have limits. Took me more than a short while to figure out I had to ensure all containers in the pod have resource limits.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @nakamume's answer, make sure to double check sidecar containers.
For me, I forgot to declare requests for GCP cloud-sql-proxy sidecar which had me pulling hairs for couple of hours.